# How can a nested route's parent get a reference to the nested child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the routes

```
<Router>
  <Route path="browse" component={Browse}>
    <Route path="foo" component={Foo} />
    <Route path="bar" component={Bar} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Browse is a wrapper that has a render function of

```
render() {
  return this.props.children;
}
```

How can I grab a reference to the child component (Bar or Foo)?

When I inspect `this.props.children` I only see the `Route` component. I need the instance of the component that was passed into the Route component

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, use React.cloneElement to pass a `ref` property to the child:

```
render () {
  return React.cloneElement(this.props.children || <div />, { key: key, ref: 'child' });
}
```

Then the child can be referenced using `this.refs.child`